# Browsing problems

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, error

I'm facing a little hitch, I managed to install and run my Tor browser; I am able to access all the Tor seacrch engines, but when I click some links on the Hidden wiki I get this error message.

> "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at:- so and so"

I tried turning my firewall off. Still problem not solved. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to connect to hidden wiki?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to access hidden services.
It's pretty common for hidden services to be down and sites like the hidden wiki reporting them as still active.

If I'm right then there's nothing you can do about it, sadly, except waiting to see if they come back online later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Hidden Services, those things go up and down quite a bit. You would just have to wait, or find another service to browse in the mean time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your firewall - your computer is only talking to the tor network.

The tor exit nodes actually access the servers you're asking for, and some of them refuse to accept connections from exit nodes (for whatever reason). That, or slow tor nodes on your path, causes this message. (I often get this for duckduckgo.com.)